# Groups acting on categories produce 2-cocycles

Tags: ct.category-theory, group-cohomology, group-actions

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\newcommand\id{\mathrm{id}}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category (such that each hom sets are $\mathbb{C}$ linear spaces) and $G$ be a group. We say that $G$ acts on $\mathcal{C}$ if for every object $C \in \mathcal{C}$ and $g \in G$ we have another object $g \cdot C$, and $e \cdot C=C$ and $(gg') \cdot C=g \cdot (g' \cdot C)$. Moreover for every $f \in \Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(C,D)$ we have another morphism $g \cdot f \in \Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(g \cdot C,g\cdot D)$ and $(gg') \cdot f=g\cdot (g' \cdot f)$ as well as $e \cdot f=f$. Finally we assume that $g \cdot (f \circ f')=(g \cdot f) \circ (g \cdot f')$ and $g \cdot \id_C=\id_{g \cdot C}$. Suppose that for each $C \in \mathcal{C}$ there are invertible elements in $\Hom(C,g\cdot C)$ and assume that for each $C$ we have $\Aut(C) \cong \mathbb{C}^*$. We choose an invertible element $\alpha_g \in \Hom(C,g \cdot C)$ for each $g \in G$ and $C \in \mathcal{C}$. Consider $c(g,h):=(\alpha_{gh})^{-1} \circ (g \cdot \alpha_h) \circ \alpha_g \in \Aut(C)$.

> I would like to prove that $c$ is a two cocycle (where $g$ acts on $\Aut(C)$ trivially).

Comment: Do you really mean $\operatorname{Aut}(C) \cong \mathbb C$, or $\operatorname{Aut}(C) \cong \mathbb C^\times$?

Comment: Yeah, sure-thanks